# Error: Cannot autodetect which importer to use for "packages.config"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, json.net, nuget-package

I am trying to use a NuGet-Package (Json.net) in Visual Studio 2010 and everytime I try to compile my solution I get the following Error:

**Cannot autodetect which importer to use for "packages.config". There are no importers which handle this file type. Specify the importer that handles this file type in your project.**

If have allready reinstalled the package, reinstalled NuGet itself.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Best regards

Flopi